# Post a feed in Community Chatter Group

Tags: apex, feeditem

I have a private chatter group in community. I want to post something in this group by System Admin.

When system admin create a FeedItem and putting ParentId = groupId programatically then getting following Exception :

> INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access
>   rights on cross-reference id:

I have also changes the Group Access as public or Unlisted, but error remain the same.
Please help me for the same.
Follwing is code :

```
FeedItem feed = new FeedItem();

feed.Body = 'Hello from Admin';

feed.ParentId = '0F9M00000009V7v'; // Community's Chatter Group ID 

feed.visibility = 'AllUsers';

insert feed;
```

Comment: Does the system admin user have explicit access to the Group?

Comment: Yes. system admin user have explicit access to the Group @Sebastian Kessel

Comment: Class is sharing included.

Comment: Try setting feed.NetworkId to the community's ID also. If the NetworkId isn't set, it defaults to the internal network, which the Chatter group is not a part of. You also don't need to set feed.visibility, because it only applies to posts on records (not groups).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have fixed this issue.
I have passed Network scope id.

feed.ParentId = '';  // Community's Chatter Group ID

feed.NetworkScope= ''; // ID of community (network)